# How to order entities by many-to-many relationship using the Hibernate Criteria API?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to order my entities by many-to-many relationship.

Assume that my domain is the following:

```
@Entity
public class Field {
  ....

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name="field_crop", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="field_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="crop_id")})
  @OrderBy(value="name")
  private List<Crop> crops;

  ....

}

@Entity
public class Crop {
  ....

  private String name;

  ....

}
```

Suppose that in my domain I have the following data:

- Filed1 { crops: {Lemon} }
- Filed2 { crops: {Kiwi, Apricot} }
- Filed3 { crops: {Apricot} }
- Filed4 { crops: {Avocado, Banana} }

Using the `@OrberBy` annotation on the `@ManyToMany` relationship, I will have that `Crop` elements in the list will be ordered by its name:

- Filed1 { crops: {Lemon} }
- Filed2 { crops: {Apricot, Kiwi} }
- Filed3 { crops: {Apricot} }
- Filed4 { crops: {Avocado, Banana} }

The expected result of fetching all Field entities, ordered by the name property of Crop entity, is:

- `Filed3`
- `Field2`
- `Field4`
- `Field1`

How I can do this via **Hibernate Criteria**?

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you write a `Comparator` and sort the list in a `@PostLoad` event listener within the entity class.

Comment: Ok, I can do this in memory; but if I use pagination?

Comment: Well, you are not paginating the collection, but the overall result, so that doesn't matter. Either way, fetching a collection and paging the overall result doesn't work that great as Hibernate has to fetch the whole result set and do in-memory pagination. If you want efficient pagination, I would recommend you take a look at Blaze-Persistence which handles this efficiently: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/#pagination